# specifying order of vertices of a triangle in opengl

Tags: opengl

A noob graphics / openGL question w.r.t. drawing the first triangle in the XY plane. As I understand the vertices need to be specified in counter clockwise order so that the normal is along the Z direction and will therefore be rendered by default. The question I have is whether there is a way one can specify the 3 vertices in any order but specify the normal attribute separately to accomplish this ?

Comment: As long as "Face Culling" is not enabled, the winding order is irrelevant. See [OpenGL wiki - Face Culling](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Face_Culling). The normal vector is only important for the light model.

Comment: Thanks @Rabbid76. If face culling is enabled, presumably the ordering has to be determined by computing the cross product to get the normal with current ordering and then based on the dot product with the provided normal decide whether or not to swap the vertices so they align with the direction of the provided normal?

Comment: Face Culling has nothing to do with the normal vector. The faces are culled depending on the winding order of the vertices projected on the the view port.

Comment: If you have a triangle (A, B, C) and a normal vector N, you can test that the points are ordered counterclockwise with respect to the normal vector with `dot(cross(B-A, C-A), N) > 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as "Face Culling" is not enabled, the winding order is irrelevant. See [OpenGL wiki - Face Culling](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Face_Culling). The normal vector is only important for the light model.
Face Culling has nothing to do with the normal vector. The faces are culled depending on the winding order of the vertices projected on the the view port.

If you have a triangle (`A`, `B`, `C`) and the normal vector `N` of this triangle, you can test that the points are ordered counterclockwise with respect to the normal vector with `dot(cross(B-A, C-A), N) > 0`. This does not mean that the face is also counterclockwise in the projection on the viewport. The winding order of the face in the viewport depends on how you are looking at the face.

If all faces of a closed volume have the same winding order, this can be used for Back Face Culling. Triangles viewed from the front retain the winding order in the projection, but triangles viewed from the back have the reverse winding order when projected.

Answer (score 0):

the default setting for glFrontFace is counter clockwise and if you want to set it to clockwise you can use

```cpp
glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE); //so you can see the diffirence
glFrontFace(GL_CW);     //clockwise
glFrontFace(GL_CCW);    //counter-clockwise
```

The setting for glFrontFace determines if the triangle is facing the camera or not so the triangle won't be visible to the camera (it won't be textured or colored).